# With HDMI audio, sound volume control does not work in Gnome-3.38 on FreeBSD-12.1

Tags: audio, freebsd, gnome3, bsd, hdmi

I have a 2nd Gen Intel Sandy bridge Core i3 system with integrated graphics. I am using HDMI output which is connected to my monitor from where the jack is connected to my 2.1 Logitech speaker system. My current operating system is FreeBSD-12.1 and it supports almost all devices. I have installed Gnome-3.38 and using it. At the top right, you have mic and volume control slider located. The problem is, this slider does not increase or decrease sound volume. Only thing it does is, if I push down, then it will mute the audio. Sound works with Intel Cougar Point HDMI, but neither pulseaudio nor Gnome-volume-control is useful. I have to manually use mixertui>pcm to increase or decrease sound volume. To get the HDMI sound output to work, I have added `hw.snd.default_unit=4` to /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
cat /dev/sndstat     
Installed devices:
pcm0: <Realtek ALC892 (Rear Analog 5.1/2.0)> (play/rec)
pcm1: <Realtek ALC892 (Front Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm2: <Realtek ALC892 (Rear Digital)> (play)
pcm3: <Realtek ALC892 (Rear Digital)> (play)
pcm4: <Intel Cougar Point (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play) default
No devices installed from userspace.
```

The HDMI audio's driver used snd_hda.
Is there a solution to map Gnome's volume control to use the correct audio source, such that Gnome volume control is useful.

[image: gnome-control-centre sound settings]

Comment: So far no solution is working. The pavucontrol shows no configuration.